# Modificar DataContext de una Vista desde ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Buenas tardes compañeros. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo modificar el DataContext de una vista con su ViewModel, desde otro ViewModel o desde el mismo ViewModel.

```
public partial class Window2 : UserControl
{   
    public Window2()
    {
        Window2ViewModel vm2 = new Window2ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm2;
        InitializeComponent();
    }      
 }
```

Gracias.
Un saludo César

Answer (score 0):

Si lo declaras fuera del constructor podrás acceder a las propiedades del VM en cualquier metodo de la clase y así modificarlo:

```
public partial class Window2 : UserControl
{   

    Window2ViewModel vm2 = new Window2ViewModel();
    public Window2()
    {

        DataContext = vm2;
        InitializeComponent();
    }      

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vm2.PropiedadViewModel = valor;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta. Pero el código me sigue sin funcionar.

El programa es una prueba para utilizarlo luego en otro proyecto.
Básicamente son dos UserControl dentro de una ventana, cada uno con su respectivo ViewModel. Implemento los interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged y 
ICommand.

En la vista1

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="30" Height="120"    CommandParameter="Button1ViewModelIzdo" Command="{Binding Btn1Command}">
```

En el ViewModel1:

```
   public class Window1ViewModel : NotifyBase
   {
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);
    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent;// = delegate { };

    private ICommand _btn1Command;
    public ICommand Btn1Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _btn1Command ?? (_btn1Command = new  RelayCommand((parameter) => Bnt1Action(parameter)));
        }
    }

    private void Bnt1Action(object parameter)
    {
        String msg = parameter as String;
        ThrowEvent?.Invoke(this, new CustomEventArgs(msg));
    }
```

En la Vista2 hay un TextBlock

```
  <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="Data" Text="{Binding   Path=Data,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
```

Y en el ViewModel2

```
  public class Window2ViewModel : NotifyBase
{
    private Window1ViewModel _Thrower;

    public Window2ViewModel()
    {
        _Thrower = new Window1ViewModel();
        _Thrower.ThrowEvent += ( emisor, e) => { ChangeData(emisor , e);      };
    }

    private string _data;

    public string Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set{
                if (_data != value)
                {
                    _data = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Data");
                }
            }
     }

    private void ChangeData(object emisor, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        Data = e.msg;
        MessageBox.Show("Hell0");
    }
}
```

La clase CustomEventArgs tiene una propedad msg.
  Pero no me lanza el evento.
¿Qué es lo que hago mal ?

Comment: Hola Cesar, sería interesante que esto lo añadieras a la pregunta original y no a la "respuesta" recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo